# Why notification message is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to show a notification message in IE11, But not working. Any other method is there for IE to show notification messages. If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

```
if(!("Notification" in window)){
console.log("Browser not supported");
}else if(Notification.permission === "granted"){
 console.log("Show content for New Message");
}
```

Comment: Internet Explorer [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/?search=notification) the Notification API

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the **sbgib** for using the `Alert()` as a workaround for Notification API in the IE 11 browser. You can also try to apply the desired styling for your notification text and try to display it on the webpage.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT: i want to show notification message on desktop..not only in web

Comment: In that situation, I suggest you upgrade to the [MS Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) browser that supports the Notification API as this is not possible with the IE 11 browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Because IE doesn't support the `notification` API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Browser_compatibility

I'd suggest dropping support for IE, yourself, as even Microsoft no longer supports it. It's market share is way below 1.5%, no longer worth it generally.

Comment: Can we use any plugin like push.js and notify.js for desktop notifications?

Comment: No, `push.js` is based on `notify.js`, and `notify.js` uses that `notification` api that IE doesn't support.

Comment: Any other way is there? for IE 11?

Comment: No. IE simply doesn't support desktop notifications. Your only option is to use `alert`, which is just not that good...

Comment: Can we use promise-polyfill?? is it possible? https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-polyfills/0.1.41/polyfill.js

Comment: No, as I said, IE does not support notifications whatsoever. It's not possible.

Comment: Ok..How we can show alert in desktop side? alert will be work on browser side only rite?

Comment: As I said, ___it is not possible___.

Comment: https://ie-web-notifications.github.io/    What is this plugin or software? :

Comment: Ok..Thank you so much for you response

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use `alert()` on older browsers, e.g.:

```
if(!("Notification" in window)){
   console.log("Browser not supported");
   alert("my message");
}else if(Notification.permission === "granted"){
   console.log("Show content for New Message");
};
```

Otherwise, if you're looking for better UX than that, you could write the message to the page.

It would also be a reasonable decision to only use the feature where it is supported. People using IE are unlikely to expect notifications from their browser!