# Why notification message is not supporting in IE11 any technical reason

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Anyone can explain technically why the notification message is not supporting in the IE11 browser. The reason is IE11 browser engine(Trident, Chakra) or any other reason?

```
var permission = Notification.permission;
```

Comment: It's not implemented.

Comment: @Omkar76: Where it is not implemented? in browser engine side or any other?

Comment: @SaranS, it looks like you had asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389132/why-notification-message-is-not-working-in-ie11) yesterday where community members had informed you that [Notification API](https://caniuse.com/notifications) is not supported in the IE 11 browser, and because of this reason your code for notification is not working with the IE browser. IE is a legacy browser and will not receive any new updates. If it is necessary for you to use the notification API then I suggest you make tests with the Edge Chromium browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

basicly, i think any mordern web browser contains a browser engine(rendering engine) and a javascript engine. a browser engine is in charge of html+css parsing and rendering, and Notification api is part of this engine. Javascript engine foucus on javascript compiling and running.

as you say so, trident is IE11's rendering engine, if it has notification api, IE11 will support `Notification.permission` in your code. why not, technically microsoft does not offer the update for his trident engine.

Comment: IE11 has no support for Notification API at all, your answer is misleading

Comment: certainly not, microsoft don't offer update for new features, because they focus on edge browser now. i just said you can't use it on IE because microsoft don't offer it,what's wrong?

Comment: if you just need notification to work on IE, try some thirt-party libs or npm packages, I haven't tried. i just googled this problem, this is what i got, may or may not work. 
 https://ie-web-notifications.github.io/

Comment: ie-web-notifications.github.io  need to install software from client side

Comment: sorry, does not know more,

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in IE11 (see the table on the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission) because IE has no support for Web Workers.

Comment: Any javascript plugins or software are there to interact with trident engine to implement notification message?

Comment: No, nothing unfortunately. What are you trying to accomplish with IE?

Comment: Just i am trying to show message like notification message in browser and desktop side  in IE11

Comment: Why are you using IE11?